# The case of the mysterious retreating bishop

Tags: positional-play, caro-kann

In the [following position](https://lichess.org/ca5y7U1t/white#28) from a Caro-Kann fantasy gone wrong, the engine suggests 15.Bf2 with advantage of (+2.5) among other close-by candidates such as Bf4 (+2.2) and Rfe1 (+2.0).

```
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "r2q1rk1/pp1n1pp1/1np1p2p/4P3/2PP4/2PQBN2/P5PP/1R3RK1 w - - 2 15"]

1. Bf2
```

But why? On the surface level, I see some immediate disadvantages:

- Primary: Blocks in the f-rook.
- Medium: Disallows Bd2 to defend against Na4. (Though Qc2 can also do that.)
- Lesser: Reduces control over Qg5 and removes possibility of (unlikely) Bxh6.

I do see some smaller advantages:

- Bg3 supports an eventual Nd6.
- Out-of-pawn-chain mobility: Bh4 is possible to control f6 and d8.
- Bishop is "less vulnerable"... though it is unclear what could attack it anyways. f5-f4 looks silly since exf6 creates an isolated e6 pawn.
- If Rfe1 is next, it's advantageous to have already vacated the e-file.

Comment: Bh4, Nd2 Ne4 could be one. alo Bh4 g5 Nxg5 hxg5 Qg3 looks interesting but didn't calculate. try moving the rook back and forth a8-c8. engine will reveal what Bf2 was up to?

Comment: *Out-of-pawn-chain mobility: Bh4 is possible to control f6 and d8.* -> yup, this is it !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this has to do with central pawn play, in particular white's e-pawn and black's c-pawn.

White's pawn on e5 is *very* valuable, and must be protected, and c5 is black's only good pawn break to open the position.

When c5 eventually gets played, the e-pawn is suddenly under a lot of pressure. Taking on c5 would break the pawn chain with tripled pawns, black already has a knight on d7, and queen to c7 would add yet another attacker.

White thus has two main goals:

- Add defenders to the e-pawn
- Keep some control over the c5 square.

Here we see the main moves crystallize out: Moving the rook to e1 adds a defender, and Bf4 or the Bf2-Bg3 manoeuvre recruits the bishop as well (both unblocking the future e-file rook). The difference between the two bishop moves is that Bf2 keeps the bishop on the same diagonal as the key c5 square.

A concrete variation to illustrate this difference:

Black can attack the queen, threaten a fork, and thus achieve c5, for some activity and a still somewhat playable position

```
[title "Bf4"]
[fen "r2q1rk1/pp1n1pp1/1np1p2p/4P3/2PP4/2PQBN2/P5PP/1R3RK1 w - - 0 4"]

1.Bf4 Nc5 2.Qe2 Nca4 3.Qc2 c5
```

The same line would go horribly wrong if the bishop moved to f2 instead, ending up in black losing a knight.

```
[title "Bf2"]
[fen "r2q1rk1/pp1n1pp1/1np1p2p/4P3/2PP4/2PQBN2/P5PP/1R3RK1 w - - 0 4"]

1.Bf2 Nc5 2.Qe2 Nca4 3.Qc2 c5 4.dxc5
```